# Is there a table or list of tare weights of empty spools of various manufacturers?

Tags: filament

It would be helpful to me if I knew in advance how much the ***empty*** filament spool weighs.

Not having emptied any spool yet, I can't contribute data points, but has anyone compiled a list of empty weights from various manufacturers and sizes?

I am asking the question because when I open a fresh spool I am curious how close it is to 'what it says on the tin'. And to find out how much I got on a "transitional" or "imperfect" spool.

Comment: (I post no answer just a alternative way) I got various spools from a single manufacturer, so the only solution for me was to not throw away empty spools that i don't have in my "collection". I assume you want to meassure the filament that is on your spools left. My experience: I measured 2 spools of the same type and they were 5 g off to each other. So 2 ways left: measure the spool at opening (be aware of the "bonus" of filament) and have a collection or a good table whit your real spools by your own.

Comment: And BTW, if you are doing this to try to use every last bit of filament, my advice is **Don't** . A few meters' worth  of filament costs almost nothing, and the hazard of running out mid-print is nasty.  At the very least, if you're going this route, install an "out of filament" switch into your printer.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is a table on [Reddit - Empty spool weights for estimating remaining filament](https://www.reddit.com/r/3Dprinting/comments/4hlwse/empty_spool_weights_for_estimating_remaining/) which suggests that the norm (in 2015) was between 170 and 330 grams for a 1 kg spool, superficially in a bimodal distribution clustered around the high and low points. Presumably these were for 3 mm filament, this post dating to before the popularity of 1.75 mm...

Manufacturer's have an incentive to reduce the mass of their spools, or even ship without spools, since the shipping cost will eat into their profit margin.

Answer (score 4):

I use the [3D Printing Wiki's Spool Weight page](https://3dprintingwiki.mywikis.wiki/wiki/Spool_weight).

Comment: +1 - Whilst this *seems* like a link-only answer (well, let's face it, it *is*), there isn't really any other way of adding this link as an answer - it is clearly not *terribly practical* (although not impossible - I did it for Sean's answer) to block-quote the whole page in this answer - it would just be a snap-shot in time. This sort of illustrates that there is an issue with this type of question (w.r.t. Stack Exchange's format) - even though the question is rather a useful one.

Comment: Using `sed` and/or `awk` (or Perl or Python (Pandas),  blah blah, etc.), one *could* easily (or more easily than manual transcription) scrape the info from the page and then, using that data, create a [markdown table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202193/280335)

Answer (score 2):

Extracting the data from the table linked to in [Damien's answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/23153/4762):

| Manufacturer | Flavor (type, size, etc) | Year | Spool Weight, g | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123-3D |  |  | 198 |  |
| 3DActive | PLA, 0,5kg | 2021.0 | 195 g | Spool by Häfner , model: SD 200/52-43K , Diameter=200 Width=44 CoreDiameter=52 |
| 3D Online |  |  | 227 |  |
| 3D Ware |  |  | 211 |  |
| 3D-Fuel | PLA, 1 KG | 2021.0 | 262 | Ribbed style sides. Very consistent weight across 7 tested spools. This is just under their claimed weight of 265g. |
| 3D-Fuel | PLA, 1 KG | 2021.0 | 288-294 | Solid style sides. Weight ranged across 3 samples. |
| 3D Fuel |  |  | 264 |  |
| 3DFIL | 1kg |  | 235 g | Diameter=200, Width=63, Core diam=54 |
| 3dJake | 250g |  | 108 g | Diameter=140, Width=44, Core diam=51 |
| 3dJake | TPU 750g |  | 212 g | Diameter=200, Width=51, Core diam=53 |
| 3dJake | 1kg |  | 240 g | Diameter=200, Width=75, Core diam=52 |
| 3dJake | 2.3kg |  | 605 g | Diameter=300, Width=103, Core diam=51.5 |
| 3dJake | 4kg |  | 870 g | Diameter=350, Width=110, Core diam=51.5 |
| 3dJake | 8kg |  | 1045 g | Diameter=355, Width=182, Core diam=36 |
| 3DO | PETG, 1kg | 2023.0 | 255 g |  |
| 3d Online | PLA 1kg |  | 208 g | Diameter=198, Width=70, Core diam=57 |
| Abfil | 750g/1kg |  | 248 g | Diameter=200, Width=67, Core diam=53 |
| AIO Robotics | PLA 500g V1 |  | 115 |  |
| AIO Robotics | PLA 500g V2 |  | 210 |  |
| Amolen |  |  | 190 |  |
| Amolen rev.2 |  | 2023.0 | 148 |  |
| AmazonBasics | PLA, Silk PLA | 2023.0 | 264 |  |
| Amazon Basics | 1kg |  | 200 g | Diameter=200, Width=75, Core diam=53 |
| AMZ3D | PETG, 1kg | 2022.0 | 230.6 g | Diameter=200, Width=65, Core diam=55 |
| AMZ3D | PLA, 1kg | 2018.0 | 230 g | Diameter=200, Width=65, Core diam=55 |
| Anet | 1kg PLA |  | 226 g | Diameter=200, Width=65, Core diam=56 |
| Arianeplast | 750g |  | 224 g | Diameter=200, Width=45, Core diam=55 |
| Arianeplast | 1kg |  | 226 g | Diameter=200, Width=65, Core diam=55 |
| Arianeplast | 2,3k |  | 680 g | Diameter=300, Width=100, Core diam=55 |
| Atomic Filament | PLA, 1kg | 2015.0 | 319 |  |
| AzureFilm | PLA, 1kg | 2021.0 | 163 | Older design, they have a new one for 2022 |
| AzureFilm | 1000g (and 750g wood), black with small Cores | 2023.0 | 220 | Source: AzureFilm customer support |
| Basicfil | PLA, 500g | 2021.0 | 187 |  |
| Bambulab | 1KG White plastic | 2023.0 | 207 g | Cardboard ring in center weights 36 g so total weight is 243 g |
| Basicfil | 1kg |  | 225 g | Diameter=200, Width=80, Core diam=50.5 |
| CC3D |  |  | 164 |  |
| CC3D | PLA MAX | 2021.0 | 153 | Diameter=198, Width=64, Core diam=53 |
| Clas Ohlson | PLA, 1kg | 2021.0 | 175 | old spool design? |
| Cookiecad | PLA |  | 177 |  |
| Comgrow |  |  | 207 |  |
| Coex LLC | PLA, 1kg | 2020.0 | 335 |  |
| COEX | PLA, 1 KG | 2022.0 | 320 | They are switching to cardboard soon. |
| ColorFabb | 1kg |  | 240 g | Diameter=200, Width=66, Core diam=62 |
| ColorFabb | 2,3kg EcoPla |  | 590 g | Diameter=300, Width=100, Core diam=55 |
| Creality | 1 Kg, old |  | 141 |  |
| Creality | 1 Kg, new |  | est. ~200-220 | near identical design to newer Gembird spools |
| Creality | CR-PLA(PLA+) |  | 140 |  |
| Creality | 1kg |  | 138 g | Diameter=200, Width=63, Core diam=54 |
| Creality | 1kg Hyper ABS | 2023.0 | 180 g | Cardboard Spool, Diameter=200, Width=58, Core diam=88 |
| Creality | 1kg Hyper PLA | 2024.0 | 173 g | Cardboard Spool, Diameter=200, Width=64, Hole diam=55 |
| Dagoma Chromatik | 750g |  | 204 g | Diameter=200, Width=52 |
| Dayfil | 1kg carton |  | 190 g | Diameter=200, Width=80, Core diam=56 |
| Devil Design | 1kg plastic |  | 257 g |  |
| Devil Design | 333g plastic |  | 148 g |  |
| Dikale | 1kg |  | 178 |  |
| Dikale | Old |  | 196 |  |
| Duramic 3D | cardboard |  | 132 |  |
| Duramic 3D | 1kg Cardboard | 2022.0 | 136 | Diameter=200, Width=65, Core diam=55 |
| Duramic 3D | PLA+, 1kg | 2022.0 | 236 | Diameter=200, Width=67, Core diam=55 |
| Elegoo | PLA, 1 KG | 2022.0 | 171 | Cardboard Spool |
| Eono (Amazon) | 1kg |  | 192 | Amazon |
| EPESTOEC | 1KG Spool, PLA | 2023.0 | 159g | Black Spool, 5 Window |
| Eryone | PLA 1kg |  | 216 g | Diameter=200, Width=64, Core diam=55 |
| Eryone | TPU 500g |  | 190 g | Diameter=200, Width=37, Core diam=53 |
| Eryone | 1kg spool |  | 186 |  |
| Eryone | PLA Marble, 1kg | 2020.0 | 181 | Diameter=200, Width=63, Core diam=54 |
| Eryone | Cardboard, 1kg |  | 187 |  |
| eSUN | PLA+, eMarble, eSilk, eTPU |  | 242 | Weight is an average of 10 empty spools |
| eSUN | eSilk | 2021.0 | 211 |  |
| eSun | Transparent |  | 214-220 g | Diameter=200, Width=60, Core diam=51 |
| eSun | standard |  | 230 g |  |
| eSun | Réutilisable |  | 160g | Diameter=200, Width=65 |
| eSun | 1kg noire |  | 250 g | Diameter=200, Width=64, Core diam=54 |
| eSun | 500g transparent |  | 203 g |  |
| eSun | 500g noir |  | 212 g |  |
| eSun | 1.75mm PLA+ Grey | 2023.0 | 633 | Diameter=269, Width=102, Core diam=53 |
| eSun | 1.75mm ePLA-ST Grey | 2022.0 | 262 | Diameter=199, Width=65, Core diam=54 |
| eSun | 1.75mm PLA+ White | 2022.0 | 266 | Diameter=200, Width=64, Core diam=54 |
| eSun | 1.75mm ePLA+HS Black Cardboard | 2023.0 | 153 | Diameter=200, Width=63, Core diam=54 |
| Extrudr | PLA 1,1kg |  | 240 g | Diameter=200, Width=66, Core diam=62 |
| Extrudr | TPU 750g |  | 228 g | Diameter=200, Width=53, Core diam=53 |
| Extrudr | Extrudr 2.5kg |  | 590 g | Diameter=300, Width=100, Core diam=55 |
| Fillamentum |  |  | 233 | Craft Filament |
| Filament-PM | 500g Spool |  | 205 |  |
| Filament-PM | 1kg Spool |  | 225 |  |
| FilamentOne |  |  | 220 |  |
| Flashforge | ABS, 1kg | 2020.0 | 176 |  |
| Flashforge | PLA, 1kg |  | 175 |  |
| Form Futura | rPLA, 750g |  | 151 |  |
| Francemaker | 1kg |  | 205 g | Diameter=200, Width=63, Core diam=52 |
| Francofil | 500g |  | 227 g | Diameter=200, Width=55, Core diam=52 |
| Francofil | 750g-1kg |  | 246 g | Diameter=200, Width=67, Core diam=52 |
| Francofil | 5kg-10kg |  | 1050 g | Diameter=335, Width=245, Core diam=51 |
| Geeetech \ Giantarm | PLA 1kg spool |  | 180 |  |
| Geeetech | 1kg |  | 183 g | Diameter=195, Width=64, Core diam=64 |
| Gelo | 1kg |  | 186 |  |
| Giantarm | 1kg |  | 197 g | Diameter=200, Width=65, Core diam=– |
| Gizmo Dorks | 1kg |  | 156 |  |
| GNVTNTP | TRICOLOR CoExtruded PLA 1KG | 2022.0 | 156 | Cardboard Spool |
| GoHigh | 1kg |  | 127 g | Diameter=194, Width=60, Core diam=72 |
| Grossiste3d | PLA 1kg |  | 215 g | Diameter=198, Width=65, Core diam=54 |
| Grossiste3d | PLA 500g |  | 208 g | Diameter=200, Width=35, Core diam=54 |
| GST3D | PLA 1kg |  | 200 g | Diameter=196, Width=63, Core diam=52 |
| GST3D | PLA 1Kg |  | 212gr but other spools: 241gr |  |
| GST3D |  |  | 207 |  |
| Hatchbox | Old |  | 224 |  |
| Hatchbox | PLA, 1kg | 2020.0 | 245 | Diameter=200, Width=67, Core diam=55 |
| HZST3D | 1kg |  | 177 |  |
| Inland | 1kg |  | 222 |  |
| Inland | 500g |  | 196 |  |
| Inland | Reusable |  | 205g, 240g* | *240g with the 35g inner tube left over from Inland 1kg PLA+ Refills |
| Ice | 750g |  | 200 g | Diameter=198, Width=56, Core diam=53 |
| Jayo | 1KG Spool, PLA | 2023.0 | 135g | Cardboard |
| KIMYA | PETG-S, 750g | 2023.0 | 242 g |  |
| Kingroon | PLA, 1KG spool | 2022.0 | 166.6g |  |
| Machines3d | 750g |  | 203 g | Diameter=200, Width=52, Core diam=53 |
| Maker Geeks | 1kg |  | 193 g |  |
| Material4print | 1Kg Spool PETG | 2020.0 | 240 g | Diameter=200, With=53, Core diam=54 |
| Markforged Onyx | 800cc/960g |  |  |  |
| MatterHackers | build |  | 250 |  |
| MatterHackers | 1kg PLA (MH Build) | 2019.0 | 228 |  |
| MatterHackers | build PLA | 2022.0 | 213 |  |
| MECH Solutions | PLA+, 1kg | 2022.0 | 254 | Diameter=199, Width=63, Core diam=54 |
| MiKA3D | PLA, 500 g |  | 115 g | Same spool as AIO Robotics 500g spool |
| Nanovia | 500g Spool | 2014.0 | 255 |  |
| Nanovia | 500g Spool | 2021.0 | 182 |  |
| Nanovia | 2kg Spool | 2021.0 | 668 |  |
| Neofil | 750g |  | 210 g | Diameter=199, Width=53, Core diam=53 |
| Novamaker | PLA, 1kg |  | 180 |  |
| Numakers | PLA+, 1kg |  | 200 |  |
| Octofiber | 1kg |  | 240 g | Diameter=200, Width=55, Core diam=53 |
| Overture | type I (1 kg), PLA, PETG | 2023.0 | 238 |  |
| Overture | type II |  | 187 |  |
| Overture | Cardboard |  | 176 |  |
| Overture | Cardboard 2023 |  | 170 |  |
| OWL | PLA, 1kg |  | 186-190 |  |
| Paramount 3D | 1kg |  | 208 |  |
| Plastika Trček | 1kg | 2019.0 | 218 |  |
| PlastSpaw | 0,7..1kg |  | 200g | Spool have smooth sides, Diameter=200 Width=66 CoreDiameter=50 |
| Proto-Pasta |  |  | 100 |  |
| Prusa Research | Prusament 300g Mini Spool |  | 130 |  |
| Prusa Research | Prusament, PLA, 1kg |  | 193 | Diameter=200, Width=72, Core diam=50 |
| Prusa Research | Prusament, PLA, 2kg |  | 226-228.5 | Diameter=200, Width=123, Core diam=50 |
| Prusa Research | Made for Prusa Research |  | 234 |  |
| Polymaker | Polycast, 750g |  | 224 |  |
| Polymaker | Polyterra 1KG |  | 187 |  |
| Polymaker | PolyTerra PLA, 1 kg | 2022.0 | 137 | Cardboard Spool, printed weight 140g |
| Prima Value | 1kg |  | 245 g | Diameter=200, Width=75, Core diam=53 |
| Prinsfil | 1kg |  |  | Diameter=200, Width=57, Core diam=78 |
| Printed Solid | PLA 1.75mm 1kg plastic spool |  | 326 |  |
| Push Plastic |  |  | 328 |  |
| Real Filament | 1kg, cardboard |  | 208 |  |
| RECREUS | PETG, 750g | 2023.0 | 232 g |  |
| Replitech | PLA 1.81kg (4Lbs) 600M Spool | 2022.0 | 178 g | Spool size: 210mm diameter x 86mm width; Center Core: 52mm diameter |
| Redline Filament | 1kg |  | 200 g |  |
| Renkforce | PLA, 1kg |  | 179 |  |
| Repkord | PLA |  | 193 |  |
| Rosa3d | PLA-PETG-800g |  | 231 g | Diameter=200, Width=53, Core diam=53 |
| Rosa3d | 800g transparente |  | 242 g | Diameter=?, Width=?, Core diam=? |
| RS Pro | 1kg |  | 237 g | Diameter=200, Width=75, Core diam=53 |
| Sainsmart | TPU 800g |  | 187 g | Diameter=200, Width=62, Core diam=57 |
| Sainsmart | TPU 250g |  | 108 g | Diameter=155, Width=37, Core diam=54 |
| Sakata | 1kg HR870 |  | 257 g | Diameter=200, Width=66, Core diam=53 |
| SIMAX3D | PLA 1kg | 2020.0 | 202 | Diameter=200, Width=74, Core diam=53 |
| Smart Materials (Makershop) | PLA 750g |  | 240 g | Diameter=200, Width=53, Core diam=53 |
| Sunlu |  |  | 150 |  |
| Sunlu | PLA+ 1kg | 2023.0 | 132 |  |
| Sunlu | PLA+ 1kg | 2023.0 | 155 |  |
| Sunlu | PLA+ old |  | 145 g |  |
| Sunlu | PETG 1kg |  | 130 g |  |
| Sunlu Masterspool | 1kg |  | 200 g |  |
| Sunlu |  |  | 133 |  |
| Sunlu | 250g spool |  | 55 |  |
| Steadytech | 1kg |  | 179 |  |
| StrongHero3D |  |  | 151 |  |
| Spectrum |  |  | 247 |  |
| 3D Solutech |  |  | 173 |  |
| SK-Honpo | PLA, 1kg | 2022.0 | 171 | Japanese distributor |
| Stronghero3D | Black Spool, 1 kg, 4 windows | 2022.0 | 154 | Black Spool, 4 windows (with bars) |
| Stronghero3D | Black Spool, 1 kg, 5 windows | 2022.0 | 123 | Black Spool, 5 windows |
| Stronghero3D | Clear Spool, 1 kg, 5 windows | 2022.0 | 121 | Clear Spool, 5 windows |
| Suntop | PLA, 1kg | 2022.0 | 177 |  |
| Sparta ABS+ | ABS+ | 2022.0 | 157 | Clear Spool |
| SOBV3D | 1kg |  | 210 g | Diameter=199, Width=70, Core diam=51 |
| SOBV3D | 1kg Démontable |  | 152 g | Diameter=200, Width=71, Core diam=52 |
| TecBears |  |  | 133 | seems to be Sunlu spool |
| Thumwan | 1kg |  | 192 g | Diameter=199, Width=66, Core diam=54 |
| Tianse | PLA, 1kg | 2021.0 | 180 | Diameter=196, Width=60, Core diam=75 |
| Tinmorry | 1kg |  | 186 g | Diameter=198, Width=65, Core diam=55 |
| Tinmorry |  |  | 184 | Similar to Eryone |
| Torwell3D | PLA, 1kg | 2020.0 | 185 |  |
| TTYT3D | PLA, 1kg | 2022.0 | 173 | Similar to DO3D Spool |
| TTYT3D | 1KG cardboard | 2023.0 | 121 g |  |
| Verbatim | PETG 1kg |  | 238 g | Diameter=200, Width=75, Core diam=52 |
| Voolt3D | PLA, 1kg | 2022.0 | 209 | Brazilian manufacturer |
| Voxelab | PLA Pro, 1kg | 2022.0 | 172 |  |
| Voxelab | PLA, 1kg | 2022.0 | 137 |  |
| Wanhao | 1kg |  | 239 g | Diameter=195, Width=57 |
| Warhorse |  |  | 133 | seems to be Sunlu spool |
| Yoyi |  |  | 175g |  |
| Yoyi | TPU |  | 169 g |  |
| Yuaneang | 1kg PLA | 2018.0 | 202 g | Solid plastic spool. |
| Zyltech | PLA, 1 KG | 2022.0 | 94 | 5 Spoke plastic spool. |
| Ziro |  |  | 226 |  |
| Zortrax | 800g |  | 183 g |  |
| Zortrax | 1Kg |  | 178 g |  |

Source: [3D Printing Wiki's Spool Weight page](https://3dprintingwiki.mywikis.wiki/wiki/Spool_weight)

Table created using Github:[greenonline](https://github.com/greenonline)/[HTMLTableToMarkdown](https://github.com/greenonline/HTMLTableToMarkdown)

Answer (score 1):

Following on from [Sean's excellent answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6558/is-there-a-table-or-list-of-tare-weights-of-empty-spools-of-various-manufacturer/6560#6560), here is the (out of date) table in question:

Image: [Empty spool weight table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Mdi0.png)

In table format:

| Brand | Size | Year | Color | Width (mm) | Diameter (inner/core/outer) | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3D Solutech | 1kg | 2015.0 | Black | 65.0 | 57/81/199 | ~173g |
| 3D Supply Source Transparent PLA/PETG | 1kg | 2015.0 | Black | 65.0 | 57 / 81/ 199 | ~173g |
| Atomic Filament | 1kg | 2015.0 | Black | 72.0 | 52 / 98 / 204 | ~319g |
| Atomic Filament | 1kg | 2016.0 | Black | 74.0 | 52 / ? / 201 | ? |
| Colorfabb | 750g+ | 2015.0 | Clear | 57.0 | 53/105/200 | ~236g |
| eSun Inland | 1kg | 2015.0 | Black | 67.0 | 53 / ? / 199 | ~224g |
| eSun Intservo PLA/ABS | 1kg | 2015.0 | Clear | 64.0 | 52 / 90 / 200 | ~253g |
| HanBot | 1kg | 2014.0 | Black | 78.0 | 40 / ? / 198 | ? |
| Hatchbox ABS | 1kg | 2015.0 | Black | 62.0 | 32 / 58 / 200 | ~226g |
| Hatchbox ABS | 1lb | 2015.0 | Black | 61.0 | 32 / 58 / 163 | ~157g |
| Honeycomb Drone | 1kb | 2015.0 | Clear | 53.0 | 52 / 60 / 220 | ~183 |
| IC3D ABS | 2.5lbs | 2014.0 | Black | 74.0 | 52 / ? / 203 | ? |
| Invent-a-Part PLA | 1kg | 2014.0 | Black | 74.0 | 57 / 96 / 198 | ~227g |
| JustPLA Chroma Line PLA | 1kg | 2015.0 | Black | 93.0 | 57 / 95 / 180 | ~197g |
| MadeSolid PET+ | 1lb | 2014.0 | Black | 55.0 | 52 / ? / 199 | ? |
| MadeSolid PET+ | 1kg | 2014.0 | Black | 71.0 | 53 / 93 / 203 | ~345g |
| MakerGeeks Brand PLA | 1kg | 2015.0 | Black | 83.0 | 38 / ? / 190 | ? |
| MicroCenter Inland | 1kg | 2016.0 | Black | 65.0 | ?/90/? | ~224g |
| MonoPrice PLA | 1kg | 2015.0 | Black | 78.0 | 39 / 96 / 194 | ~221g |
| NinjaFlex | 500g | 2014.0 | Black | 54.0 | 52 / 94 / 200 | ~329g |
| Octave ABS | 1kg | 2012.0 | Black | 90.0 | 32 / 58 / 161 | ~168g |
| Prototype Supply | 1kg | 2014.0 | Black | 69.0 | 53 / ? / 199 | ? |
| Reprapper ABS | 1kg | 2012.0 | Black | 90.0 | 32 / 58 / 161 | ~157g |
| Sainsmart TPU | 800g | 2015.0 | Black | 65.0 | 57 / 81? / 199 | ~173g |
| Sainsmart TPU | 800g | 2015.0 | White | 84.0 | 32 / 49 / 162 | ~153g |
| SMW3D | 1kg | 2015.0 | Black | 78.0 | 32 / ? / 200 | ? |
| Taulman Nylon / TGlase | 1lb | 2014.0 | Black | 70.0 | 19 / 51 / 127 | ~90g |
| Taulman PLA | 1kg | 2015.0 | Black | 84.0 | 38 / ? / 190 | ? |
| Ultimachine PLA | 1kg | 2012.0 | Black | 71.0 | 53 / 93? / 203 | ~345g |
| Up! ABS | 700g | 2013.0 | Black | 55.0 | 53 / ? / 198 | ? |
| XYD Filament | 1kg | 2015.0 | Black | 67.0 | 53 / ? / 198 | ? |
| Yasin | 1kg | 2015.0 | Black | 60.0 | 48 / ? / 199 | ? |
| Zen Toolworks Flexible | 1kg | 2014.0 | Black | 60.0 | 52 / ? / 198 | ? |

Source: [Reddit - Empty spool weights for estimating remaining filament](https://www.reddit.com/r/3Dprinting/comments/4hlwse/empty_spool_weights_for_estimating_remaining/)

Table created using Github:[greenonline](https://github.com/greenonline)/[HTMLTableToMarkdown](https://github.com/greenonline/HTMLTableToMarkdown)